# This document must contain content type properties - Run time error - 2147216381(80041403)

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I save my file to the SharePoint folder(onedrive sync) using the following VBA code. Off late for some reasons not known to me the SharePoint properties are not displayed

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=spath & e
```

wherein spath is the SharePoint path and e is the filename.

However, if a file is saved manually to the same folder then the properties appear.

any help is appreciated

For better understanding here is a screenshot of my query [image]

Comment: What properties are you referring to? Do you try reading them from VBA? If yes, using what code?

Comment: yes i try to read the Sharepoint properties(columns exist in sharepoint list) using the ContentTypeProperties and i use the following code 'ActiveWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties("Name").Value = "Name of Sheet" '

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot save the file directly to SharePoint, then you can try a workaround - save the book on a local disk (for example, in the Temp directory) and copy this file along a path known to you, connecting it as a disk on your computer. After that, the temporary file can be deleted (or left for some time as a safety net) and the disk can be disconnected. Something like this:

```
Sub storeToSharePoint(ByVal sPath As String, sFolderName As String, sFilename As String)
Dim FSO As Object, NW As Object, sTempPath As String, ToPath As String, newFileName As String, sDrive As String
Rem First store ActiveWorkbook to Temp with name sFilename
    sTempPath = Environ("Temp")
    If Right(sTempPath, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then
        sTempPath = sTempPath + Application.PathSeparator
    End If
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=sTempPath & sFilename
Rem And now - copy to SharePoint:
    sDrive = AvailableDriveLetter() ' Try get drive-letter
    If sDrive = vbNullString Then
        Debug.Print "No free letter to connect network location - file '" _
            & sFilename & "' will not be copied"
    Else
        Set NW = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
        Call NW.MapNetworkDrive(sDrive, sPath)
        Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
        ToPath = sDrive & "\" & sFolderName & "\" & sFilename
        FSO.CopyFile Source:=sTempPath & sFilename, Destination:=ToPath
        Call NW.RemoveNetworkDrive(sDrive)
Rem If need Kill temp-file
Rem     FSO.DeleteFile sTempPath & sFilename
        Set FSO = Nothing
        Set NW = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Here sPath is your spath - root folder of your SharePoint site; sFolderName - path to folder in your SharePoint (You don't want to save all files to the root folder, you put them a little deeper, right?) and sFilename is your "e".

You also need the AvailableDriveLetter function. It is very simple, it many times published in the Internet without any unchanges (Google gives out more than three hundred thousand links). I'll put it here:

```
Function AvailableDriveLetter() As String
Dim i As Integer
    AvailableDriveLetter = vbNullString
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        For i = Asc("D") To Asc("Z")
            If Not .DriveExists(Chr(i)) Then
                AvailableDriveLetter = Chr(i) & ":"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks but the issue is not about saving the file to sharepoint i am able to do that.... the issue is that i am not able to access the properties (sharepoint columns) when I save the file with the code.in my question.