# VBA unable to fetch the content type properties from Sharepoint

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, metadata

I have my SharePoint connected to my onedrive and use the following piece of code to save the file in the onedrive folders (Which in turn syncs to my Sharepoint) and update the content type properties.

The file gets saved in sharepoint but I am getting the following error when the second line of code is about to run - This document must contain content type properties - Run time error - 2147216381(80041403).

Upon investigation, I noticed that the SharePoint properties which should have been fetched by default is not getting fetched (Screenprint for reference)

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\meetrk85\OneDrive folder\Documents\ONE.xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties("Approval Status").Value = "Uploaded"
```

However, if I manually save the file to the said folder it does fetch the properties.

[image]

PS: This is a duplicate of my query raised with no luck 6 days ago hence have rasied it afresh
[This document must contain content type properties - Run time error - 2147216381(80041403)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63645501/this-document-must-contain-content-type-properties-run-time-error-2147216381)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [This document must contain content type properties - Run time error - 2147216381(80041403)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63645501/this-document-must-contain-content-type-properties-run-time-error-2147216381)

Comment: no it does not help